# Sails JS Model Rest API

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, sails-mongo

I'm new to sails.js and find something strange. I have create a model user like :

```
sails generate api user
```

So i have access to :

```
http://localhost:1337/user/
```

and

```
http://localhost:1337/user/create?name=joe&test=true
```

But why sails allow me to add any fields I want in the model like :

```
http://localhost:1337/user/create?name=joe&test=true&toto=ok&titi=okToo
```

toto and okToo are not under my model in api/model/User.js:attributs

I miss something maybe if anyone can help me to understand this.
For me sails.js have to save only fields i put on model:attributs file or throw an exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit the creation of fields to only those you specific in the model. Sails has this feature to allow for quickly mocking up your site.

http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/ORM/model-settings.html?q=schema

Comment: Did you know how can I add policies to restful blueprint url please ?

Comment: The section that reads protecting controllers from policies, that is the same as blueprints http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Policies